# Text file to 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

Im reading a text file line by line and now I want to arrange it in a 2d array but I'm stuck.
here's the code:

```
BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Data.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println(line);
        }
            bfr.close();
```

So I got it to print the text file but now I want to arrange it in a 2 dimensional array.
any help?

Comment: I don't see any attempt to create or fill array in your code. Also we don't know how would you like to fill it.

Comment: Arrange What?Lines/words?

Comment: 2D array implies 2D array of char, correct? char[][]?

Answer (score 0):

There is a great class in java which is call Scanner and can be use for many things related to the stream data.

```
File file = new File("data.txt");     
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can use it for a file. It will read line by line.
Here it's printing but store it in array and it's done !

Comment: Only use `Scanner` if you really need it. If you just want to read a file line by line, a `BufferedReader` or something else is the way to go. `Scanner` is really, really slow. You'll realize the difference even with very small files (a few thousand lines) immediately.

Comment: Alright, i'll keep it in mind.
But the logic is still the same.

Comment: I really like `Scanner` for its syntax, too, but it's really slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try making an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> bob = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then you can simply go:

```
bob.add(line);
```

Then to print it out, you can go:

```
for(int x = 0; x < bob.length; x++) {
    System.out.println(bob[x]);
}
```

That should work. :)

Comment: Not `bob[x]` and `bob.length` Use `arList.get(i)` and `arList.size()` for `ArrayList`:)

Answer (score 0):

Text to a 2D array? Interesting and very common. As mentioned in a previous answer a Scanner could be useful, however your method of getting the text file is fine; even though a scanner may have a little bit better speed performance (conduct some research. :P)

The way I would tackle this problem is by adding a delimiter in between each tile(?) placed. Example:

```
1:1:1:1:1:1:1
1:0:1:0:0:0:1
1:0:0:0:1:0:1
1:1:1:1:1:1:1
```

This allows you to grab a line and then split it up using the `String.split(String delimiter)` method. As LouisDev said, a Scanner is better, so I will use that:

```
File file = new File("data.txt");     
try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    int y = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        y++;
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So we have our way of getting the line and storing it into our variable *y*. This will be used in the following method which displays a way of gathering all the contents within the string and storing it into a 2D array. Effectively, this is the answer to your question.

```
File file = new File("data.txt");     
try {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
  int y = 0;
  int[][] map = new int[methodParsedHeight][methodParsedWidth];
  while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] lineSplit = line.split(":");
    for(int x = 0; x < lineSplit.length; x++ {
      map[y][x] = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[x]);
    }
    System.out.println(line);
    y++;
  }
  return map;
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This effectively should fix the problem occurring. If not, give us a comment!

Jarod.

Comment: What is the methodparseheight and width?

Comment: The final block of code is assumed to be out into a method (or constructor). As parameters for that method, it should be `public int[][] getMap(int width, int height)`. Obviously now, `methodParsedWidth` is now just `width` as the same with `methodParsedHeight`; that now becomes `height`. - Problem solving is a skill a programmer needs. This is hardly a problem solving question. I would expect that this is figures out on your own...